# Aurelia import library after library

Tags: javascript, aurelia

So I'm kinda new to Aurelia and the JavaScript import syntax and I'm working on an application that requires jQuery UIs `draggable` and `droppable`. Since those widgets don't work on a mobile device I need to use the [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) library.

The issue I'm encountering is the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined
```

It apparently appears when the jQuery UI Touch Punch library has been loaded *before* jQuery UI.

This is how my `aurelia.json` file is set up:

```
"dependencies": [
      // ....
      {
        "name": "jquery",
        "path": "../node_modules/jquery/dist/",
        "main": "jquery"
      },
      {
        "name": "jquery-ui",
        "path": "../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui",
        "deps": ["jquery"]
      },
      {
        "name": "touch-punch",
        "path": "../node_modules/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch",
        "deps": ["jquery-ui"]
      }
    ]
```

And I have these imports in my view model:

```
import 'jquery-ui';
import 'touch-punch';
```

For some reason everything works fine but I still have that console error.

How do I find out for certain that the jQuery Touch Punch library has loaded before jQuery UI and if it does how do I make sure it loads *after* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that the module loader is importing both scripts concurrently, and `touch-punch` is winning the race, therefore, it's being loaded first. I believe this problem is out of Aurelia's control.

Nevertheless, `jquery-ui-touch-punch` wasn't made for modular systems. The best way to import it is using `<script>` tags or prepending it into the bundle. Considering that `jquery-ui-touch-punch` depends on `jquery-ui` which depends on `jquery`, the workaround is prepending all of them. Like this:

```
"name": "vendor-bundle.js",
"prepend": [
  "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
  "node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/resources/scripts/configure-bluebird.js",
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
  "node_modules/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js",
  "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
],
"dependencies": [
   ...
]
```

Afterwards, remove them from `dependencies` and remove the `import` statements.